# Allowing Fixed DIV to continue to move horizontally

Tags: css, html, fixed, frames

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EzuTT/

CSS

```
#bottomfadebar {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 2; 
    bottom: 0px;
    width:267px;
    height:84px;
    background-color:#666;
}
#content{
    width:2000px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    This is all of the data. Theres lots of it.  so the user will have to scroll horizontally.  the bottom bar should go out of view as you scroll further to the right because there's so much data.  the bottom bar should only stay "fixed" to the bottom, not to the left hand corner.
</div>

<div id="bottomfadebar">
    THIS SHOULD SCROLL HORIZONALLY AS THE PAGE DOES
</div>
```

Ultimately, the #bottomfadebar div continues to stick in the bottom-left hand corner as you scroll to the right to see more of the content div.  I'm trying to figure out how to allow the bottomfadebar DIV to scroll off to the left of the screen, but still fix at the bottom of the window as it's currently doing.

------EDIT!!!

Ok, so I kinda blew it on this because I thought it would be easily explained but then I realized the absolute factor would come in.  It actually should reside inside of a NAV div thats centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5GuG/4/

It DOES need to stick to the absolute left:0 inside the "container" area....I should have specified, I apologize.  Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Use `position:absolute`?

Comment: how about `absolute` instead of `fixed`

Comment: Ok, so I kinda blew it on this because I thought it would be easily explained but then I realized the absolute factor would come in.  It actually should reside inside of a NAV div thats centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5GuG/4/

It DOES need to stick to the absolute left:0 inside the "container" area....I should have specified, I apologize.  Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DS6yg/1/  .  Notice how on page load, everything is nicely centered and 400 px, and the footer is sticking to the bottom.  Now take your jfiddle windows and make the output window smaller so that you get horizontal scroll bars.  if you scroll to the right, you'll see that the header and content scrolls off the page as it should, the footer does not scroll off the page horizontally.  I'm merely trying to keep the footer scrolling in line with the header and content.  Sorry about not doing a great job of explaining this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code in your Fiddle.

I moved `bottomfadebar` inside of content, change the height of content to 100% and changed the `bottomfadebar` to absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/EzuTT/1/ - Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks Justin, I actually kinda blew it on this because I thought it would be easily explained but then I realized the absolute factor would come in. It actually should reside inside of a NAV div thats centered. jsfiddle.net/u5GuG/4 It DOES need to stick to the absolute left:0 inside the "container" area....I should have specified, I apologize. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Im still a little confused... Only because it seems like what you are asking is already done in your new Fiddle

Comment: Ok, let me simplify.  Take a look at this completely new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LVBVq/  So the table is 400 width and centered.  If I currently used bottom 0 on "thefooter", it would throw it to the bottom of the page perfectly (with the correct rest of the syntax).  But what happens is if a viewer has a resolution smaller than 400 width, they get horizontal scroll bars.  So if we scroll horizontally, "thefooter" stays in place where as "thecontent" scrolls off the left of the screen.  Ultimately, I'm merely trying to get "thefooter" to scroll relatively to the rest of the data scrolling.

Comment: Better yet @doitlikejustin , take a look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DS6yg/1/  .  Notice how on page load, everything is nicely centered and 400 px, and the footer is sticking to the bottom.  Now take your jfiddle windows and make the output window smaller so that you get horizontal scroll bars.  if you scroll to the right, you'll see that the header and content scrolls off the page as it should, the footer does not scroll off the page horizontally.  I'm merely trying to keep the footer scrolling in line with the header and content.  Sorry about not doing a great job of explaining this!

Comment: Ohhh I see now. Ok... this works :) http://jsfiddle.net/DS6yg/2/ Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: the problem with absolute is that it doesn't stick to the bottom.   I updated your version with more content: http://jsfiddle.net/DS6yg/3/   see how when you have to scroll down, the footer doesn't stick?

Comment: hey @doitlikejustin, that DOES work, although it has some funky issues with infinity vertical scrolling.  Quick question, do you know how you'd change the formula to make the javascript do the absolute horizontal scrolling instead of the bottom:0 "fixing"?  Ultimately the vast majority of my users are going to have resolutions large enough (I know...responsive screen size :), I unfortunately don't have the option to change the framework completely right now) to now worry about the horizontal scroll, so the fix is more for when that happens rather than vice versa.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: So you want the CSS to do the fixed bottom and the JS to handle a case where the user scrolls left?

Comment: I see you already accepted my answer. But I played around with it again. Check out this version... http://jsfiddle.net/DS6yg/9/ I've never spent so much time on someone else's problem before. Lol

Comment: hey @doitlikejustin , thanks man, I can't get my mind around the fact that its so complicated to do this lol.  I appreciate the help.  I took your latest version and kinda went from there.  If you want one other point of interest... try scrolling to the right (after you make your window smaller) then scroll down, it jumps everything back off...bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a little jQuery for that, if you don't mind ;)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#bottomfadebar").css("left", (-1 * $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/Gqpmf/

**Update:** now I think I got it, you want the `#bottomfadebar` to scroll along the bottom of the screen while you scroll the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var window_width = $(window).width(),
        window_scrollleft = $(window).scrollLeft(),
        content_width = $("#content").width(),
        bottomfadebar_width = $("#bottomfadebar").width(),

        content_path = content_width - window_width,
        bottomfadebar_path = window_width - bottomfadebar_width,
        bottomfadebar_left = 0;

//  Equations:
//  content_pos = window_scrollleft / content_path;
//  bottomfadebar_pos = bottomfadebar_left / bottomfadebar_path;
//  content_pos = bottomfadebar_pos;

    bottomfadebar_left = window_scrollleft / content_path * bottomfadebar_path;

    $("#bottomfadebar").css("left", bottomfadebar_left + "px");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/Gqpmf/2/

**Update 2:** I think I still donn't get it, but if you want it to stick to the `[bottom,center]` screen position, then this css is a go:

```
#object {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px; /* half of the width in negative */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/Gqpmf/3/

**Update 3:** really my last guess. If you want an item to be absolute positioned inside another element and relative to it, you have to set the container element's position to relative (or absolute).

```
#container {
    position: realtive;
}
#object { /* inside #container */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; /* will stick to the left side of #container */
    bottom: 0; /* will stick to the bottom side of #container */
}
```

Comment: CSS might be easier for what he is trying to do. jQuery seems a little overkill, maybe?

Comment: Actually it is much harder to do this with CSS without some expensive tradeoffs of compromises. This jQuery is clear and easy as hell, tho you may call it overkill :) This is not the best solution, but one that works.

Comment: hey Aorcsik - I actually failed to mention it needs to reside inside of a container, I thought the fix would be universal.  Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/Gqpmf/1/  Any thoughts?

Comment: @aorcsik not quite, that stays at the bottom and goes from left to right (although thats quite cool :) ), I need it to be able to scroll off the left of the page as people are scrolling to the right.  Really what Im looking for is for it to never change positions on the page.  Its definitely like an "absolute" position, with the caveat is that its "absoluteness" is relative to the div or table its embedded in...so its not sticking to the bottom left hand corner of the actual web browser, but instead sticking to the  left hand corner of a centered table, bottom of browser I guess.... thx much!!

Comment: @JohnEgbert well not sure if I get it this time, but maybe (see update). I still can't see what is the visual goal what you are trying to achieve, leave off the css and html parts, just say what you want to see.

Comment: Ok, Take a look at this completely new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LVBVq/  So the table is 400 width and centered.  If I currently used bottom 0 on "thefooter", it would throw it to the bottom of the page perfectly (with the correct rest of the syntax).  But what happens is if a viewer has a resolution smaller than 400 width, they get horizontal scroll bars.  So if we scroll horizontally, "thefooter" stays in place where as "thecontent" scrolls off the left of the screen.  Ultimately, I'm merely trying to get "thefooter" to scroll relatively to the rest of the data scrolling.

Comment: Better yet @aorcsik , take a look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DS6yg/1/  .  Notice how on page load, everything is nicely centered and 400 px, and the footer is sticking to the bottom.  Now take your jfiddle windows and make the output window smaller so that you get horizontal scroll bars.  if you scroll to the right, you'll see that the header and content scrolls off the page as it should, the footer does not scroll off the page horizontally.  I'm merely trying to keep the footer scrolling in line with the header and content.  Sorry about not doing a great job of explaining this!

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/DS6yg/7/ In this case the `left` property of the footer is set the same as the left offset of the header, this way they move together horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch bottomfadebar position to 'absolute'. As you already have 'bottom:0' set it will stick to the bottom of the page. It will not remain visible when you scroll horizontally as an absolutely positioned element will default to 'left:0' unless you specify otherwise (except in older versions of IE (7 and under I think) where you may need to declare 'left:0;' to avoid odd rendering.

Comment: Ok, so I kinda blew it on this because I thought it would be easily explained but then I realized the absolute factor would come in.  It actually should reside inside of a NAV div thats centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5GuG/4/

It DOES need to stick to the absolute left:0 inside the "container" area....I should have specified, I apologize.  Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed positioning, use absolute and set your left and bottom attributes to 0.
This will position the div at the bottom left of the page, instead of the bottom left of the browser viewport.

```
#bottomfadebar {
position:absolute;
z-index: 2; 
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width:267px;
height:84px;
    background-color:#666;
}
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/u5GuG/3/

Comment: Ok @james, so I kinda blew it on this because I thought it would be easily explained but then I realized the absolute factor would come in. It actually should reside inside of a NAV div thats centered. jsfiddle.net/u5GuG/4 It DOES need to stick to the absolute left:0 inside the "container" area....I should have specified, I apologize. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: No problem, so you are trying to get the navcontainer div to be in the center of the page, and to have bottomfadebar sit at the bottom left, or the bottom center of navcontainer?

Comment: @JamesHebden take a look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DS6yg/1/  .  Notice how on page load, everything is nicely centered and 400 px, and the footer is sticking to the bottom.  Now take your jfiddle windows and make the output window smaller so that you get horizontal scroll bars.  if you scroll to the right, you'll see that the header and content scrolls off the page as it should, the footer does not scroll off the page horizontally.  I'm merely trying to keep the footer scrolling in line with the header and content.  Sorry about not doing a great job of explaining this!